# Can RecyclerView preload the first n item on the list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a listing of some item and I am using `Glide` to load an image onto an ImageView. The problem is, if a particular item, scroll-enter the screen, that is the only time I saw image is being drawn using `Glide`. This is noticeable when I put crossfade when the image has finished loading.

I know from the start the number of items needed and couple of other items like header and footer. I am thinking of just making a very long view to handle everything and dynamically add those known items at `onCreate` and just use `ScrollView` which I have done. I currently implemented a simpler way using a `RecyclerView` but I having trouble regarding the timing of `onBindView` call.

What I want is to load first 5 items before they become visible into the screen. This I hope will trigger the method where I bind the image onto the ImageView with Glide before it is fully visible into the screen.

I followed this [tutorial](https://androiddevx.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/recycler-view-pre-cache-views/) and its not working for me. Here is my current setup:

```
mComicListingAdapter = new ComicListingsAdapter(getContext(), Constants.CHAPTERS, (ComicListingsAdapter.Callback) getActivity());
mRecycleViewHomeScreen.setAdapter(mComicListingAdapter);
mRecycleViewHomeScreen.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecycleViewHomeScreen.setItemViewCacheSize(42);
mRecycleViewHomeScreen.setLayoutManager(pcll);
```

Is this possible in RecyclerView? Or maybe I should try dynamically creating `ImageView` and appending them to a parent `View` as I have done so. It looks great but there is a lot of things to do in my case using this method. I am just curious if I can direct `RecyclerView` to load n-amount of items in advance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I've found a [blog post](https://androiddevx.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/recycler-view-pre-cache-views/) where author suggest to extend LinearLayoutManager and override getExtraLayoutSpace().

And it worked. More items were preloaded depending on the number of pixels returned in getExtraLayoutSpace().

P.S. I've not checked yet how that affects performance, especially on pre-lollipop devices.

Sample:

```
val customLayoutManager = CustomLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView).apply {
    layoutManager = customLayoutManager
    ... // 
}

class CustomLayoutManager(context: Context?) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    override fun getExtraLayoutSpace(state: RecyclerView.State?) = 2000
}
```

Comment: surely a recycler view should not be used for this matter, but hey this solves it :D

Comment: Now getExtraLayoutState is already depreciated. The new method is `void calculateExtraLayoutSpace(@NonNull RecyclerView.State state,@Nonnull int[] extraLayoutSpace) `. This is intended to use for developers to override and implement the own custom pre-cache logic.

Answer (score 2):

`Views` are created dynamically at runtime and you can only access view items at `onBindViewHolder` method of adapter. You want to load images before setting adapter to recycler view. Firstly the `getItemCount` method is being called which will look for number of items and then `onCreateViewHolder`  method is called to draw a row into your `RecyclerView`.

So this is not possible in `RecyclerView` to access items before setting any `Adapter`. You need to achieve this in some other way by dynamically creating an `ImageView`, for example.

Comment: Although, I found the problem, the animation is the culprit. It made it look like it is loading when it fact it isn't. I remove the animation and quick scroll on my views and I barely notice any loading at all